# How to rotate a RectangleShape in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, drawing

Is it possible to rotate a rectangle shape in VB.net? 
Code to my rectangle shape is this

```
baseDice.Parent = shapeContainer
baseDice.CornerRadius = 5
baseDice.Height = 50
baseDice.Width = 50
baseDice.BackColor = Color.Blue
baseDice.BackStyle = BackStyle.Opaque
baseDice.Left = 50
baseDice.Top = 50
baseDice.Name = "baseDice"
```

`baseDice` is an object of  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RecntangleShape`

Comment: Roate as in 2d Animation

Comment: Change Left, Top, Width, and Height depending on how you want to rotate it?

Comment: I am attempting to shift its position or change its size. rotate as in, how earth rotates on its axix

Comment: Then just change the fields I told you....

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, Oops, I meant I am not attempting to shift its position or change its size. rotate as in, how earth rotates on its axis

Comment: Then what are you trying to do.... go from vertical to horizontal?

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, Check [this](http://www.draftsperson.net/images/2/23/Rotate_Family_1.jpg) out. May it will give you an idea... I could find other images

Comment: Look at this http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbforums/Topic21965-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the VB Class Matrix, here's an example

```
Dim myPen As New Pen(Color.Blue, 1)
Dim myPen2 As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 150, 50, 200, 100)
Dim myMatrix As New Matrix()
myMatrix.Rotate(45, MatrixOrder.Append)
e.Graphics.Transform = myMatrix
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen2, 150, 50, 200, 100)
```

In the Matrix.Rotate you give it the angle and what the type of transform is (you can use Append to constantly rotate by an angle)

e is of PaintEventArgs type

Comment: What about the `e`, what is it. Shall I put this code in `_load()` event

Comment: There clarified what the e meant.

Comment: I am really a starter guy in vb.net, I tried placing this on form's load event, it didn't worked, modified the e to take PaintEventArgs, and it didn't work then too

Comment: My method that does the drawing, draws the shape without asking any parameters, how will it take that `e`

Comment: I finally got this working, but I am trying to simulate a dice rolling, how will I put image in it, how will i make it rounded. And after i rotate the shape, the previous shape remains there, how to remove old drawing....

Comment: That's another question in and of itself, it seems you are kind of new to this so you may want to google some quick tutorials so that you understand how a lot of this drawing and such works in VB and how you can create objects to store the information that you need to draw.