# Can a HScrollbar be used to rotate a label?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rotation, scrollbar, angle

I am currently doing work for my college and I need help with a specific part of the program (Visual Studio 2010).

I have a HScrollbar that has a minimum of 0 and maximum of 85, which are supposed to represent angle values. I have it so that as you scroll the scrollbar the value is displayed in a label underneath(lblangle.text = HScrollbar.value)and above the scrollbar is a 90 ° vertical rectangle (colored -in label). How can I make it so that the colored in rectangular label rotates with the value in the label (lblangle) bellow. So for example lblangle will display 40 and so the rectangle rotates 40 degrees clockwise. I would also like this to update real time so that every time the scrollbar is scrolled the colored-in label is rotated accordingly.

Images of visuals and what should be the relevant code.

[image: image of the design of the form]

[image: Image of the code to do with the labels and HScrollbox]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post code as an image. It is usually harder to read and make any use out of. -- As for your issue; in WinForms you cannot rotate objects. You can draw them so that they look rotated, but it's usually a bit costly and hard to perform as the control's bounds would have to be adjusted. WPF is a much better platform for this.

Comment: You could make a UserControl in WPF which contains a rotatable label that you then add to your WinForms project via an [**ElementHost**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx), however getting the non-label part of the host's rectangle to be transparent is going to be very tricky (if not even impossible).

Comment: After actually inspecting your first picture (should've done so first :) ) what you're doing is possible if you just draw the block using a control's [**`Paint` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) (preferrably the form's paint event, in this case) _AND_ you don't need to have anything beneath the label. -- See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921585/how-to-rotate-a-rectangleshape-in-vb-net).